# AKS creation through CLI fails: Reconcile standard load balancer failed

Tags: azure-cli, azure-aks

I have created the AKS using below CLI command on countless number of occasions. I had no problem until today.

```
az aks create --resource-group rg  --name ama --generate-ssh-keys --location southeastasia 
--aad-server-app-id xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxx --aad-server-app-secret @xxx?=1[xxx:xxx:xxxx:xxxx  
--aad-client-app-id xxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx   --client-secret xxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx 
--aad-tenant-id xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx  --service-principal xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx
--node-count 3
```

Today, I am getting the below error. I tried two different regions and two different subscriptions.
but same error.

```
Deployment failed. Correlation ID: a3aa4495-7669-4338-bc86-95b7d8b28f8f. Reconcile standard load balancer failed. Details: standardLoadBalancerReconciler retry failed: 
Future#WaitForCompletion: the number of retries has been exceeded: StatusCode=502 
-- Original Error: Code="InvalidGatewayHost" Message="Host name resolution failed 
for 'Microsoft.Network'; cannot fulfill the request.".
```

Anybody experienced/ experiencing this?

Comment: Im am experiencing the same issue, also when trying to provision an AKS cluster. I tried it via Azure CLI, Az Powershell, the portal and in two regions (west und nord europe).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Azure has a problem affecting resource creation:

> Starting at 08:45 UTC on 04 Jun 2020, a subset of customers may experience issues with >resource creation for services that depend on the Azure Resource Manager (ARM) platform.
>
> We have determined that ARM functionality is being impacted by an underlying Networking >issue, and this manifests as latency or failures when creating resources for some >services. We are actively working to troubleshoot this, and the next update will be >provided in 60 minutes, or as events warrant.

https://status.azure.com/en-us/status

Also see this question:

[InvalidGatewayHost host name resolution failed for Microsoft.network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62193157/invalidgatewayhost-host-name-resolution-failed-for-microsoft-network)